# Invoking a Powershell script and Displaying its output in a Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-forms-designer

I've got a powershell script that outputs to the console every 5 seconds, like so:

```
While($true)
{
    Write-Output "test"
    Start-Sleep -seconds 5
}
```

I want to have a windows form application that will allow the user to enter the filepath of the script, hit a button, and then display any further output from this script in a window like so:

[image]

However, I am running into trouble actually getting this script to startup. Based on reading different threads, here's what I've got at the moment:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filepath = textBox1.Text;
            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                string s = "";
                var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                Process process = new Process();

                info.UseShellExecute = false;
                info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                info.FileName = "powershell.exe";
                info.Arguments = filepath;

                process.StartInfo = info;

                process.Start();

                s += process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                process.WaitForExit();
                textBox1.AppendText(s);

            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Error: Invalid file path.";
            }
        }
```

Now, this does open a powershell window, so I know that it at least starts the process, but I'm not seeing it actually run my script, and I know that the file exists at the path I'm entering. When I run `powershell.exe {filepath}` in a command prompt terminal, the script runs fine.

The end goal is to have all output written to the white textbox on the right-hand side of the Form Desktop Application above and continually append to that textbox as the script gives output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, take the "string s  = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();" and start the thread right before the process.WaitForExit(); then you can break out of the thread once the process exit.  It is still possible that you may need to create a delegate function to print the text in your text box, if so look into delegate functions, easy to implement.

```
    Thread t = new Thread(ReadStart);
    t.Start(process);
    process.WaitForExit();


public void ReadStart(object data)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Process p = (System.Diagnostics.Process)data;
  while(true)
  {
    string s  = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    textBox1.AppendText(s);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    if (p.HasExited) break;
  }
}
```